# I need some assistance in fixing my shell bash scripts to move a file to a directory and retrieve that file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have an assignment in which I have to create two bash scripts.

One script will move a file that I create into my deleted directory, and the other would retrieve that file.

For my first script, I am having issues with steps 5-7. My step 5 was working perfectly until I added step 6, after which it started showing an error saying that it cannot move my recently created file to the directory I wanted (which is my home deleted directory that my script created).

Why would this be happening?

```
  #!/bin/bash



    #5.

    function file_inode (){

    fileName=$1
    inode=$(ls -i $1 | cut -d" " -f1)
    echo "$1_$inode"
    mv $1_$inode $HOME/deleted/$1_$inode
    }

    file_inode $1



    #6.
    function move(){

    fileName=$1
    inode=$(ls -i $1 | cut -d" " -f1)
    touch $HOME/.restore.info
    readlink=$HOME/deleted/$1_$inode
    path=$(readlink -m $1_$inode)
    echo "$1_$inode:$path">> $HOME/.restore.info 
    }

    move $1

    #7.
    function final(){

    fileName=$1
inode=(ls -i $1 | cut -d" " -f1)
    if [ $1_$inode == "*safe_rm" ] ;
    then
            echo "Attempting to delete safe_rm - operation aborted"
            exit 1
else
exit 0
fi
}

final $1
```

Comment: Check your code at: [http://www.shellcheck.net/](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Hi you guys, I was able to fix the problem that I had with my first script. I made silly syntax errors and forgot to add the touch function in my fifth question. I will try and fix up my second script.

Comment: What happens if `$1` contains a `' '` (*space*)? e.g. `script.sh "my dir/my file"`?